# Where do I find good documentation on the Jetty API?

Tags: java, jetty

I was working through an example with Jetty.  There are a few methods in the interface which aren't well documented, and so I don't know how to adjust the sample to my real world scenario.  The Jetty documentation appears to be incomplete in some sections.

For many examples that I've looked through there isn't any explanation about why they've passed certain values to certain methods.  How did they know what parameters to pass?

Are there some well documented examples or documentation that could help me to understand the code which follows:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
public class MinimalServerRest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);

     // Cannot find documentation on setInitParamter
     sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass", "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
```

}

Comment: Quite a sarcastic, and not helpful comment, Kayaman. I just went through the top ten results on Google. Most of the hits are examples using jetty, servletholder, and setinitparameter. None of them provide any explanation why they are doing things the way they are.

Comment: @Kayaman StackOverflow is supposed to be helpful site, where people are helpful and post constructive and to the point answers. You are bringing the attitude of the forums here, where people flame each other left and right, and provide indirect answers like, here your answer is in this post with 20 pages in it.

Comment: @Kayaman wow you're kind of a jerk. Maybe you should go back to the Oracle Forums where that kind of attitude is normal and expected.

Comment: @Kayaman I bet you're a joy to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good place to start:
[Embedding Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html)

Since you are trying to add a Jersey application to Jetty, you might be interested in [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http).

If you have multiple servlets, etc., you could do something as below:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(
            ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
contextHandler.addEventListener(new SomeListener());
contextHandler.addFilter(SomeFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(
            DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD,
            DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ERROR));
contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(DefaultServlet.class), "/");
contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(
            new SomeJerseyApplication())), "/basepath/*");
server.setHandler(contextHandler);

server.start();
server.join();
```

This is some sample code to get started. On top of this, if you need initParameters, you can always use the

```
contextHandler.setInitParameter("key","value")
```

where the key or value strings would be very specific to your requirements. Personally, I prefer using classes and objects instead of String based configurations when using embedded jetty.

The SomeJerseyApplication could look like this:

```
public class SomeJerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public SomeJerseyApplication() {
        packages("you.packages.that.need.to.be.scanned.for.resources");
        register(SomeProvider.class);
        register(SomeJerseyFeature.class);
    }
}
```